# Entry workflow management in Gravity Forms, mark completed

Tags: wordpress, forms, admin, gravity-forms-plugin

I would like to add another "status" in the Admin area for my entries.  The admin area lets you put a check by an entry and mark it as Unread, Starred, or Trash.  I would like to add "Completed" as an entry status.  It would be great to rename "Unread" to "Processing" as well.  Thoughts on doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following tutorial helps: http://www.stevenhenty.com/gravity-forms-approvals/

It details the steps needed to add your own custom approval process including new status choices such as pending and approved. It also provides code examples at during each stage of the tutorial and a link to the complete code hosted on github.